# Multiple arguments xargs example on downloading files with each given name?

Tags: xargs

To save with a relative given name I normally do

```bash
wget -q -O tux.png https://git.kernel.org/cgit-data/cgit.png
```

With lines made by name and path, how to use xargs for downloading files?

```bash
~ cat list
tux.png https://git.kernel.org/cgit-data/cgit.png
pallo.png https://cgit.freebsd.org/freebsd.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue happened to me recently. I think of two ways

1. xargs sh -c

```
# $a is the local file name, cut out from url, 
# $arg is the urls
cat ~/l | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do  a=$(echo "$arg"|cut -d '.' -f 7);echo $a "$arg" | wget --output-document $a "$arg";done'
```

2. sh

```
cat l | awk -F '.' '{print "wget -q  -O " "~/" $4 $0}' | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

By considering a input list, made by name and path each line, here is how to download files with multiple arguments xargs

BSD MacOS

```bash
xargs < list -L1 bash -c 'wget -q -O $0 $1'
```

GNU Linux

```bash
xargs < list -l bash -c 'wget -q -O $0 $1'
```

for parallel mode use option `-P` e.g.

```bash
xargs < list -P 24 -L1 bash -c 'wget -q -O $0 $1'
```